# How to move Button control towards X axis based on timer value in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a button in wpf and added dispatchertimer to wpf,Now I want the Button to move as the timer statrs and button should move untill timer stops.
 Could somebody help me? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Well you might better use a Storyboard, but if you want to use a timer, you can change StepValue, a value that, says, go from 0.0 to 1.0 using n steps. if your timer's frequency is f call/sec then your animation will last n/f. Then you can build a public property ButtonMargin (a Thickness ), that you update each timer call ( ButtonMargin = New Thickness(StepValue * MovingWidth, 0,0,0) ), and you NotifyPropertyChanged in the setter of ButtonMargin. Then you bind ButtonMargin to the Margin of the Button.